# Use Properties file or database to store values which is best approach?

Tags: java, properties, configuration, sms

Application was developed with multi-tenant support in which i need to send SMS to the user where i need to append the country dialing code with the user mobile number.

My question, having a separate column to store the country dialing code in the country table is good approach or to have the country code in the properties file is a good approach ?

In general what kind of values we will store in properties file (like  DB configuration settings)?

Comment: Kindly stick to one question for one answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the database connection details in the properties file and everything else in the database. If you run more than one application server with a shared or replicated database this will ensure the same data is available everywhere - this might not be a consideration now but there is no harm future-proofing!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the application you work with I think. Eithere ways it will yield the result you want. Eg: Choice could be made based on times of retrieval & frequency of change/edits.

**a.** `Times of retrieval is high - Avaoid multi times hit on DB-table`

If it is maintained in property file, then you can retieve by using java.util.Properies by loading the file. And same info if you are using in some jsp page with some ant build, retrieving is easy by reading as ant property by using ant's property ant task. It would be useful if multiple sub applications/modules are using same info.

**b.** `Frequency of edits is high & retrieval is like one time in application.`

If you want to maintain the data in DB table mapping & if it is used by some shared applications/projects then it will help in terms of maintainability.

Hit the db once based on country Or get all values & use/iterate based on requirement

Answer (score 0):

Basically it depends on how big your data is. Generally when using Swing applications, you put all translated texts in property files which may contain around 1000 properties.
But if your data contains ten thousands entries then a database would make more sense and easier to maintain.

Since you already have a database in your project, I would suggest using that and adding the country codes to the database.

Answer (score 0):

From your use case, I understand you would need to store/retrieve country codes at runtime.

Generally we use properties file to enable the user to configure external values (say, Connection properties, Output folder). Properties will be very useful for non-GUI applications.

But here  country codes are very un likely to change, you can store them in db, on top of that you may add a caching layer which enables you one time fetching. Thus you can ensure improvements in the performance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer comes down to this simple rule of thumb. State needs to be there in the database. Configuration can be externalized in property files (or other formats like YAML).

Using property files to store mutable state is a recipe for disaster, besides being an anti-pattern.

The database as a concept emerged originally out of the learnings from disasters like this one.

Thanks